# C++ Function good practices

Tags: c++

When declaring a function, I sometimes get confused about which signature it should be used. I try to always return a boolean, which shows if the function worked as expected. Then, if necessary, add either a pointer or a reference as an input argument, so I could get an actual value out of it, for example:

`bool getDistance(int& x)`

This may be a really stupid example, but I just want to show my point where I could return false in case this function does to run as expected, otherwise, I get the distance information from the function.

I think `throw` wouldn't be necessary for most cases.

Is there any standard/recommendation for that?

Comment: exception seems better, or [`std::expected<T, E>` proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0323r8.html).

Comment: You are looking for "error reporting idioms". Somewhat "canonical" C++ typically [uses exceptions](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions), although some projects prefer to use exit codes.

Comment: `std::optional` is a good way to return a value, but also be able to signal no value was returned.

Comment: Out parameters are inefficient compared to return parameters.  Moreso for more complex types, but even for primitives.

Comment: between `optional` and `expected`, which one should I prefer?

Comment: Depends under what circumstances `getDistance` would return `false`.  Are those circumstances fairly typical?  Hard to say without the implementation of `getDistance`.

Comment: my point would be actually to have a standard while coding, so the development team could also use that and avoid refactoring. But only if it makes sense.